# Angular 2/4 and scss syntax not work with build prod

Tags: angular

I have problem with scss. I have project component, that contains in his html code  4 app-tile's. I have redirect different class to each of tile and 
 that's how project.component.html code looks:

```
<app-tile class="a"></app-tile>
<app-tile class="b"></app-tile>
<app-tile class="c"></app-tile>
<app-tile class="d"></app-tile>
```

Tile.component.html code:

```
<div class="tile">
    text 
</div>
```

Now that strange problem. The style of tile works only when i use that form:
tile.component.scss:

```
.a
.tile { color: red; }

.b
.tile { color: blue; }

.c
.tile { color: green; }

.d
.tile { color: purple; }
```

When I try to set selector in one line it dosent works:

```
.a .tile { ... } // bad way
```

..but I dont know completly why? Okay, I can accept that syntax, as a last resort it works .The problem is, when I try to build project with --prod, the styles for .tile with specific class(.a, .b, .c, .d) are not loaded... Can somebody help me with solving this situation?

EDIT:

If I set:

```
.a .tile { color: red; }
```

..in developers tools -> elements - html code i see:

```
.a[_ngcontent-c11] .tile[_ngcontent-c11] {
  color: red;
}
```

but when i set:

```
.a 
.tile { color: red; }
```

i got:

```
.a
.tile [_ngcontent-c11] { color: red; }
```

How this can affect to this problem?

Comment: Could You provide the path of Your `.css` files?

Comment: update: The problem is, when I try to build project with --prod, the styles for .tile with specific class(.a, .b, .c, .d) are not loaded.

Comment: ok, where is Your styles file located?? under `assets` folder or in `styles.css`

Comment: If I have x.components.html, x.component.scss is next to him. Usually, angular creates styles.css next to index.html but i dont have used him

Comment: When You run `ng build --prod` command what's type of error occurred?

Comment: there's no error, but style's for .a .tile are not loaded

Comment: if it is possible, please include Your `.scss` file in Your question...

Comment: Okay, I have added some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.a { color: red; }

.b { color: blue; }

.c { color: green; }

.d { color: purple; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, add

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  ...
})
```

to project.component.